# T-SQL stored procedure meta data

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, metadata

Is there a way T-SQL stored procedures return meta data information of the selected rows?

This is what I want a stored procedure to return as far as considered as data:

```
ID, CollegeID, SchoolID, SanzCode, SCCode
1,  34,        75,       'X3s78V', '34SDF43SGAD46GJT65'
2,  36,        78,       'S9872a', 'S932JAGK8398998A09'
```

As part of meta-data I want to get more info, something similar to this:

```
ID, CollegeID,   SchoolID, SanzCode, SCCode
1,  34 {34-334}, 75 {/datamapper/sid?34&366}, 'X3s78V', '34SDF43SGAD46GJT65 {color:#534}'
2,  36 {45-243}, 78 {/datamapper/sid?35&454}, 'S9872a', 'S932JAGK8398998A09 {color:#a66}'
```

Any thoughts and suggestions?

Comment: from where come these additional info such as 366 in first  row and 534 in color

Comment: Meta data information also comes from SP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to store this kind of arbitrary extra information in additional columns and include them in the `select` list.

Comment: Ended up doing in additional columns. In my example. Created new columns called _CollegeID, _SchoolID and _SCCode to hold the meta data.